# Getting a strange exception with the MS Exception Handling Block

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, .net-3.5, enterprise-library

I've created a very basic Logging block and Exception Handling block. In my code, I went to go test the Exception Handling (I know the Logging block works) with the following:

```
    public void RunScriptClean()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            var b = ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Logging Policy");

            if (b)
                throw;
        }
    }
```

However, on the very first line of the catch block, I get this long winded exception and my application crashes:

`Exception occured: The current build operating (build key Build Key [Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyImpl, Logging Policy]) failed: The type 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' cannot be resolved. Please verify the spelling is correct or that the full type name is provided. (Strategy type ConfiguredObjectStrategy, index 2).`

I have absolutely no idea what it's referring to when it says the type cannot be resolved. I've added references to Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common/ExceptionHandling/Logging and Ms.Practices.ObjectBuilder2. This one class has `using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling` included at the top.

Added a screenshot of the configuration tool looking at my AppConfig file:
[image]

I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but it's tough to find a tutorial for EAB 4.1-- CodeProject has a lot for the original versions but I couldn't make much of them...

**Edit** I tried creating a new Formatter and naming it `TextExceptionFormatter` but that didn't change anything. Wasn't sure if maybe some how the `FormatterType` property on my Logging Handler was tied to that node.

And the actual block of XML from App.config:

```
  <exceptionHandling>
    <exceptionPolicies>
      <add name="Logging Policy">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            postHandlingAction="NotifyRethrow" name="Exception">
            <exceptionHandlers>
              <add logCategory="General" eventId="100" severity="Error" title="Enterprise Library Exception Handling"
                formatterType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.TextExceptionFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                priority="0" useDefaultLogger="false" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                name="Logging Handler" />
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
    </exceptionPolicies>
  </exceptionHandling>
```

I found this SO question: [Cannot resolve type runtime error after registering the Enterprise Library into the GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601885/cannot-resolve-type-runtime-error-after-registering-the-enterprise-library-into) but even after changing the Version segment of the `fullName` attribute my app still behaves the same.

Comment: That error message and screen shot both tell you that something is amiss with your reference. The exception message includes `PublicKeyToken = %token%' which is obviously not right. And your config appears to contain an exception of its own, look at the `Title` property value.

Comment: I just replaced the value of token with that, sorry-- it was pretty lengthy and seemed arbitrary. Perhaps I was wrong! As far the "Title" goes, I really wasn't sure what belongs there, I thought that'd just get used as the title for the entry in the log file. `Title. This is the title of the log entry. The default value is Enterprise Library Exception Handling. You can change the title if you want to.` - MSDN. And the Token value is simply the Formatter Type in the screenshot.

Comment: What I'm saying regarding the Title is that, from the screenshot, it looks like it is throwing an exception when it is attempting to resolve that. Personally, I never use the config tool, I just look at the actual app.config. Could you post the relevant details from that?

Comment: Alright, editted to include the actual XML

Comment: Why aren't you using the latest version of the application block, 6.0?

Comment: Because giant, global coorporation :(
The same reason this app I'm working on needs to work on XP, too! *shoots self*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, I was able to find a sample application that used the Logging handlers. Turns out I needed a reference to `ExceptionHandling.Logging`:

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging ****
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2
```

Where as I only had a references to:

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2
```

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out, and good luck going forward with this endeavor

Comment: thank you for pointing this out! In case someone else has problems finding this Assembly in EF 6, you can type that in the Package Manager Console of Visual Studio: `PM> Install-Package EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging`